Notice: Function _load_textdomain_just_in_time was called incorrectly. Translation loading for the
My website (https://vibeermag.com/) is throwing these errors when I try to access the backend and when I try to access the frontend.

Notice: Function _load_textdomain_just_in_time was called incorrectly.
Translation loading for the jetpack-social domain was triggered too
early. This is usually an indicator for some code in the plugin or
theme running too early. Translations should be loaded at the init
action or later. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more
information. (This message was added in version 6.7.0.) in
/home/wu5uhsco8fjj/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6114
Notice: Function _load_textdomain_just_in_time was called incorrectly.
Translation loading for the burst-statistics domain was triggered too
early. This is usually an indicator for some code in the plugin or
theme running too early. Translations should be loaded at the init
action or later. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more
information. (This message was added in version 6.7.0.) in
/home/wu5uhsco8fjj/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6114
Notice: Function _load_textdomain_just_in_time was called incorrectly.
Translation loading for the complianz-gdpr domain was triggered too
early. This is usually an indicator for some code in the plugin or
theme running too early. Translations should be loaded at the init
action or later. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more
information. (This message was added in version 6.7.0.) in
/home/wu5uhsco8fjj/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6114
Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces
is no longer supported in
/home/wu5uhsco8fjj/public_html/wp-content/themes/grandnews/lib/custom.lib.php
on line 573

I have tried several things like deactivating plugins from the file manager, downgrading PHP to 7.4, downgrading the wordpress version, and still nothing. Can you please help me?

The notices are coming from a lot of plugins right now: will be a short while until those all get cleaned up. The fatal error is coming from your theme: if the theme was pre-built, check to see if there's an update available. If not pre-built or no update is available, go to line 573 in lib/custom.lib.php and change the syntax to not use curly braces. If you need help with that, update your question to include the code from lines 570 to 580.

It's weird because there is no such folder inside the file manager.

Look carefully at what the fatal error is telling you. It's explaining the issue, and showing you exactly the line that needs to be changed. We don't know what line 573 looks like in your theme's wp-content/themes/grandnews/lib/custom.lib.php file, so paste in that block of code so we can help you. The rest are simply notices - not errors - and can be coming from anywhere (theme or plugins). Make sure all of your plugins and Wordpress are up to date. If you're using an off-the-shelf theme, make sure that's updated as well.

I can't access the path of what is showing the error because that folder doesn't exist in the file manager. I copy and paste the path into the explorer and I get "This directory is empty"
I also can't access the backend to update the plugins and themes (which are theoretically updated)

The file definitely exists in the relevant environment - if it didn't, PHP wouldn't be able to execute it and cause the error. I think you're somehow looking in the wrong place, or on the wrong server

It could be cached, try reloading php-fpm or apache server (depending on your setup). If error persist, make sure you checking in the correct directory e.g. you might be checking old copy of the code not the version your web server is referencing.
To address WordPress notification regarding translations, keep those plugins up to date.
